# Expressing rotations in inverted 2D axis coordinate plane?

Tags: matrix-equations, angle, change-of-basis

I'm confident with rotations as 2D matrix and used to manipulate coordinates in a orthonormal plane.

But I'm very confused when this plane has $Y$ inverted (use case: screen or paper with a top left origin).

What is the direction of rotation when I give a positive $Theta$ rotation in this inverted basis?

Comment: Have you tried solving it axis-wise for an easier case (like 2D), just writing the trigonometric equations relating lengths from respective axes. It might be insightful to look at the matrices arising from them.

Comment: It is 2D. I just said 3D matrix because it's the proper way to add translations, as well. And that I don't have the choice, because my application uses 3D matrices. Like quaternions (4D) are the proper way to solve 3D problems. I will reformulate to speak only of 2D.

Comment: Ok, I understand my mistake. In this software (PDF and XPS manipulation), they prefer to use U.M-1 instead of classical M.U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional representation of a Cartesian plane with a horizontal $x$ axis pointing to the right and a vertical $y$ axis pointing upward gives us a counter-clockwise rotation for a positive rotation angle.

But the rotation formulas just deal with numbers, not with drawings. They are all about what coordinates you put in and what coordinates come out, not where you draw those coordinates on the paper or on a display screen.

For example, the rotation by $\theta = \frac\pi2$ takes points on the positive $x$ axis to points on the positive $y$ axis, and in the meantime takes points on the positive $y$ axis to points on the negative $x$ axis.
For example, it takes $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ and takes $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0).$

With the usual "$x$ right, $y$ up" orientation of the axes, that's a counterclockwise rotation.
With the $x$ axis pointing right but the $y$ axis pointing down,
it's a clockwise rotation.